# passing multiple parameter in jsp

Tags: jsp, jstl

I want to pass two parameter from my one jsp page to another jsp page which is included.

First  JSP Code :

```
 <%
        java.util.Map map = new java.util.LinkedHashMap();
        map.put("Manage Client", "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/clients/");
     %>
     <s:message var="message" code="label.NavigationBar.add"></s:message>
        <jsp:include page="/includes/_navigation_top.jsp" >
            <jsp:param name="topLeftNav" value="${message}"/>
            <jsp:param name="parentNode" value="${map}"/>
        </jsp:include>
```

the included jsp (/includes/_navigation_top.jsp) page code is

```
<c:if test="${ param.topLeftNav ne 'Quotes' }">
        <div class="third-nav">
           <div class="bread-crum">
               <ul >
                <li><a href="${applicationScope.app_url_secure}/">Home</a></li>
                <c:if test="${param.parentNode!=null }">
                    <c:forEach items="${param.parentNode}" var="map">
                        <li><a href="${map.value}">${map.key}</a></li>
                    </c:forEach>
                </c:if>
                <li>${param.topLeftNav}</li>
              </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
    </c:if>
```

can anybody help me out where i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing oldschool *scriptlets* and modern [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info). They do not share the same variable scope. You created the `map` in *scriptlet* scope, but you're attempting to pass one in the EL scope by `${map}` which is obviously `null`.

Let the *scriptlet* (or preferably, a front controller [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)) put it in the right scope as expected by EL. E.g.

```
request.setAttribute("map", map);
```

Comment: but i need to create the map in my jsp only. Any other way to achieve in jsp through jstl?

Comment: [JSTL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) is just a presentation taglib, not a front controller or something. I now see a `<s:message>` which indicates that you're using Struts. Do the job in the Struts action class instead. Or if the data is supposed to be applicationwide, use a `ServletContextListener` instead (or something Struts-specific, if any available).

Comment: From Spring MVC? Do it in the Spring MVC controller then.

Comment: dont want to .. as the values are sort of hard codes so i passed as parameter as string use split function to display

Comment: Well, then use the old school *scriptlet* way. It's only ugly. You can also ask a more specific question how to do it in framework X.